# Is there a problem with future proofing my welding outlet?

Tags: wiring, 240v

I'm doing a fairly major remodel on my garage/workshop and so have the walls open. I'm installing an outlet for running my welder. Currently I have a small welder that needs a 30 amp circuit but I fully plan to upgrade my welding set up to a bigger 50 amp model one day down the line. My question is would it be a problem to install a 50 amp breaker, and run 6 guage wire now while the walls are open and then just put a 30 amp outlet on it? My thinking is that down the line when I upgrade welders I just have to switch the outlets not pull new wire.

Comment: Bigger wires not a problem, but would wait till you need the fifty amp breaker and receptacle.  The wires are usually hard to put in.  Don't want to wait for a 50 amp breaker to trip for a 30 amp problem in the welder.

Comment: Would sizing the wiring for 50a but selecting a 30a breaker and outlet be sufficient to code?

Comment: @Havegooda - absolutely that would be fine. The point is the wire is not the limiting factor in the circuit (no fire hazard which is the main point of code), and the breaker is sized to the actual load (though check the actual specs on the machine).

Comment: Code is mainly about minimum wire size on a circuit/breaker, you can't have smaller than.  Breakers also have a label on them saying the maximum size that can fit on the breaker, usually at least two or three sizes bigger.

Comment: Are you in a [state which has adopted NEC 2020?](https://www.iaei.org/page/nec-code-adoption)

Answer (score 2):

The breaker needs to protect the wires (i.e., you can use a breaker sized for the wires or a *smaller* breaker) and it needs to be sized to match the load. Generally the device will have a particular circuit size recommended by the manufacturer. There are some exceptions - the most common is that 15A-rated devices (i.e., using up to 12A continuous or up to 15A short term) can be on 15A or 20A circuits. There are also some exceptions, particularly with large *motor* loads due to startup requirements. But basically if your welder says "30A circuit", that is what you need to provision - 30A breaker, 30A receptacle, 10 AWG *or larger* wire.

You have two options:

- Cable - If you want to use cable, you can upsize (e.g., 6 AWG), but stick with a 30A breaker for now. That will cost you more in cable, but the only future cost will be the breaker and receptacle.
- Conduit - Install conduit. Use 10 AWG *wires* and a 30A breaker and receptacle now. Someday you can *replace* the wires with larger wires and install a larger breaker and receptacle. That may cost less now (depending on the relative cost of cable vs. conduit vs. wire) but will save money later (depending on the cost of wire at the time) and will be less work later (because fishing new wire through conduit is generally much easier than running a new cable).

Comment: You could also run upsized wire through conduit now with the intention of installing the 50A breaker and outlet later. Then, if you decide to go with something even bigger or install a subpanel, you've got conduit and can pull even larger wire if necessary.

Comment: ...and the wire could be (even bigger) aluminum, and save the cost of everything else .vs. copper wire. Virtually all 30/50A receptacles are rated for Aluminum, as are virtually all breakers.

Comment: But beware. Some places like Montgomery County, MD restrict use of aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

### Other wire options

Your idea of throwing a nice fat cable in there "now" is fine.

Somewhat better would be throwing in a nice fat *conduit* which allowed you to change the wires anytime you please.   A nice thing about conduit is you get to use THHN wire, which has a higher thermal rating and ampacity than NM/Romex. For instance copper #6 NM is 55A.  Copper #6 THHN is 65A.  Copper #8 THHN is 50A.  Aluminum #6 THHN is 50A. (assuming the only circuit in the conduit).

At #6 and larger, aluminum wire becomes a reasonable choice.  Larger sizes of aluminum have always been reliable, because a) they are landed on terminals properly rated for aluminum, and b) they are torqued to spec (or at least gud-n-tight).

Note that many/most larger receptacles are rated for aluminum wire and 75C thermal (needed to qualify for the higher amp ratings mentioned above).

Note that if your state has adopted NEC 2020, it probably requires GFCI on a 240V socket.  The only way to do this is an $80 circuit breaker.  This can be avoided by hard-wiring the device.

### Use the right socket - please

[image]

*These are the 30A versions. The 50A versions have a similar theme.*

The correct socket for a "hot-hot-ground" wiring connection is NEMA 6 type (6-30 or 6-50).

Unfortunately, "the welding community" has adopted the obsolete and illegal "NEMA 10" type as their "private little socket".  NEMA 10 is hot-hot-neutral (no ground).  There is no sense to this, since NEMA 6 sockets *are in the very next bin* at the store, but I suspect this "habit" became embedded in the 1960s when that socket was still legal for any use but dryers and ranges (and banned for those in the 1990s).

So a used welder is likely to show up with a NEMA 10 socket.  Remove it, smash it, and fit a NEMA 6 (or a NEMA 14 is also acceptable, the modern dryer/range socket).

### Think EV - it will improve your resale value.

We're seeing home-buyers offer $1000 or even $3000 premium for houses with "EV outlets" already in the garage.  (which need not be sockets; simply need to be a fat 30A+ 240V wire coming in).  *They don't even have an EV. They just think they **might** get one someday, and would rather add $5/month to their mortgage *now* rather than $1000-2000 later to hire the work done.*

So I would modify your plans *slightly* so your welder outlet counts as an EV outlet.  That means using NEMA 6 socket (again not NEMA 10) - or if you don't mind running 4-wire cable, a NEMA 14 socket.

EV chargers (they're called EVSE since they're really just a switch) don't need neutral.  Although a few simpletons think they do, and some suppliers advise you to install a NEMA 14 (SMH why? I think their logic is if you can afford a "T" car, you probably own an RV).

### Consider RVs, too.

Larger RV's (and smaller ones too) require neutral, which means they *must* use NEMA 14-50.  Smaller RVs generally have the dogbone adapter to convert 14-50 to what they need. So if an RV (or a guest with an RV) is in the crystal ball, then favor the NEMA 14-50.

14-50 is really the universal donor - it supports all RVs, all EV charging, and welders can use it too.

But if you run a NEMA 14 connector, you must run 4-wire cable with neutral. Never, ever, ever abuse ground as neutral or the other way 'round. Doing so can create an extreme danger if that wire ever has a connection problem. That's why it was banned for dryers and ranges. It was killing people - and those connections are rarely disturbed. For a more active connection like a welder or RV, *fuggedaboutit*.

### Feel free to change breaker/socket *at will*

For instance if you've decided to wire it 4-wire and 14-50 for future versatility, but your welder *today* is a 30A, feel free to install a 6-30 socket (just cap off the neutral) and replace the breaker with 30A for now.

The socket and breaker size must be matched.  Using "larger than required" wires is always allowed. The wire needs to fit on the socket, but 30A sockets should accept 50A wire like a #6. Make sure the socket is 75C rated if using THHN, and AL rated if using aluminum. Most are.